# Get data from MS Access DB using StelsMDB on Android

Tags: java, android, database, ms-access

I'm trying to access a MS_Access db using [StelsMDB library](http://www.csv-jdbc.com/stels_mdb/doc.htm). The file is on the SD card of the phone. I loaded all libraries, created the connection:

```
public class DBConnection {
    private static final String TAG = DBConnection.class.getSimpleName();

    private Connection connection;

    public DBConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(jstels.jdbc.mdb.MDBDriver2.class.getName());
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jstels:mdb:sdcard/2012xp.mdb");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e1);
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return this.connection;
    }
}
```

and it seems to work; but when i try to query something i get the following exception:

> Failed parsing query
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: unknown query object flag 3

Online i can't find any hint. I get this exception with a complex query, so i tryied to write an easier one like

`"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME"`

....but i get the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long trying i found out that jStels is not compatible with android...

Answer (score 0):

I belive you have a mistake in the connection string. You need to creat Connection object with it's atributes.

Try replacing your connection with this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jstels:mdb:sdcard/2012xp.mdb");
```

Comment: ...a little comment woudn't be bad.

Comment: The comment has been added

Comment: Please tell me the difference between my and your code. However, as i wrote, the connection seems to work, but the queries fail.

Comment: I can only guess that you are using the statment query outside the try  catch where you make the connection. If that is it, try a simple query inside the try ... catch where you have the connection. 
You can declare a statment inside the try catch and pass the query to the statment, and then execute it.

Hope this helps, if not, let me know, so I can type a code example in here